# iTerm2 shortcut for deleting selected

Tags: shortcut, iterm, macos

I've set some shortcuts in iTerm2, but I cannot find how to set MS Windows style **cut** functionality. I want to select some text (which I am able to) and then cut/past it somewhere else. I want also to delete selected text without copying it.

Simply, I want to set <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>backspace</kbd> shortcuts in iTerm2.

By default <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> is only copying selected text without removing it.

Answer (score 7):

1. Remove characters on the left, until the beginning of the word: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
2. Clean up the line: You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to clear up to the beginning.
3. Recall the deleted command: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>
4. Cancel the current command/line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>